# Analyticity of $n$-th root function

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I started studying complex integrals and some doubts arose. Among them is how to solve the following one, for example:

$$\displaystyle\int_A^B  \frac{x^{\frac{1-n}{n}}}{n}dx $$

Which clearly, its antiderivative is the $n$-th root. However, I have read that it is only possible to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus if the integrand is analytic. Otherwise, I should calculate using paths. How should I proceed? Am I correct about using paths? I'm very confused on this. Where A and B are complex.

**EDIT**

After reading the comments, I am attempted to think I understood this. Let me explain:

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus will only work if the integrand is analytic/holomorphic (which I do not know exactly what it means). Otherwise, if it is not, then we will have to integrate it through a path (which I do not know how to set a path or choose).

**EDIT II**

So, basically, if both $A,B$ are in $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < arg(z) < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the expression. becomes:

$$\sqrt[n]{B} - \sqrt[n]{A}$$?

Also, generally, if $g$ is analytic in a connected domain:

$$\displaystyle\int_A^B  \frac{dg(z)}{dz} dz = g(B) - g(A)$$

Comment: Are A or B complex?  If they are both real, the limitation on the Fundamental theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: Yes, I forgot mentioning this.

Comment: If the integrand is not holomorphic, the answer may depend on the path taken between the two points.

Comment: Alright, but what if I just know A and B, should I set a path?

Comment: Path needs to avoid a singularity.

Comment: So this is just the requirement? Could you give na example, please?

Comment: It isn't that the FTC (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) doesn't apply. The problem is, this integral *is not even defined*. Integration of complex functions of a complex variable is along a path, and this integral does not specify one. In the special case that the function is analytic (or holomorphic) *everywhere*, then the integral will not depend on which path is chosen and this pathless version integral is definable. But if the function is not differentiable at even one point, then integrals along paths passing on opposite sides of that point may have different values.

Comment: Ok, let's suppose that A and B are any complex numbers except zero. Then the integrand becomes analytic, therefore could we use the FTC, right?

Comment: The integrand is not well defined, because exponentiation with a non-integral exponent is not well defined. Even the square root function can not be defined throughout the domain of nonzero complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is, as @Lubin commented, what does $x^{1/n-1}$ mean if $x$ is complex. There are $n$ $n$th roots of a complex number. Now it is customary to chose the main branch, that is, the root with the smallest angle to the real axis, with a preference to the positive angle.

It may happen that this introduces a jump along the direct path $x(t)=A+t(B-A)$, $t\in[0,1]$, from $A$ to $B$. Using a (differentiable) path $x:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$, $x(0)=A$, $x(1)=B$, that avoids the negative real half-axis results in a continuous integrand. But with the same right one could choose a path that winds around the branching point zero multiple times, leading to multiple jumps. This is what @PaulSinclair commented, the integral is not well-defined, as it depends critically on the path chosen (and also the root branch selection).

You get less problems if you restrict $A,B$ to a convex set that does not contain the branching point/singularity $0$, and best also not the negative half-axis, the jump location of the main branch of the roots. For instance the half-plane of positive real parts fits these conditions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However what is a convex set? Another thing: if I set $A$ and $B$ to be in $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < arg(z)<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, then will it be fine?

Comment: Convex is egg-shaped. A set that contains all segments connecting points in it. And yes, that is the half plane $Re(z)>0$, so it is fine.

Comment: Fine, great. Could you take a look at Edit II, please? I want to know if I really got it.

Comment: In principle, yes to both in II. In the second case, also look at what "simply connected" means and what the situation with the logarithm is, that is, the possibility or impossibility of $\int_A^B\frac{dz}z$ inside some annulus around but excluding $z=0$.

Comment: Well, as far as I have seen, I looked at $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i$ and understood it well. I also looked at a way of taking out singularities. The only problems I have were with Cauchy's formula and Residues -- I must read it again....